# IF Statement with three possible outcomes - too many arguments?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have an IF statement which I would like to output 1 of 3 possibilities but when I enter the function, Excel reports there are too many arguments.

```
=IF([@[PM Visit Due]]<$M$1,"HIGH",IF(AND([@[PM Visit Due]]>$M$1,[@[PM Visit Due]]<$N$1),"MEDIUM"),IF([@[PM Visit Due]]>$N$1,"LOW")
```

Is there anyway to run this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When nesting IFs you add up the closing `)` at the end and not inside.

Also it will resolve in order, so the AND is not needed nor the last if:

```
=IF([@[PM Visit Due]]<$M$1,"HIGH",IF([@[PM Visit Due]]<$N$1,"MEDIUM","LOW"))
```